# WebGL - using a texture for arbitrary binary data, and floating point errors

Tags: webgl, shader

I am using an WebGL float texture to store matrices.
Every row has N matrices.

In the shader, I get these matrices, given the relative size of each vector, and each texture row.

For instance, if I have 10 matrices per row, and 10 rows, the shader gets:

```
u_vector_size = 1 / (10 * 4)
u_row_size = 1 / 10
```

With that information, I fetch 4 pixels from the texture:

```
uniform sampler2D u_boneMap;
uniform float u_vector_size;
uniform float u_row_size;

mat4 boneAtIndex(float column, float row) {
    column *= u_vector_size * 4.0;
    row *= u_row_size;

    return mat4(texture2D(u_boneMap, vec2(column, row)),
                texture2D(u_boneMap, vec2(column + u_vector_size, row)),
                texture2D(u_boneMap, vec2(column + u_vector_size * 2.0, row)),
                texture2D(u_boneMap, vec2(column + u_vector_size * 3.0, row)));
}
```

The problem? this doesn't work under some drivers.

I mostly see it on Macs, but it also happened on Windows, where the fetches get wrong data, and everything goes crazy.

I am assuming this is due to floating-point errors.

Mostly due to the fact that results change whether I use a texture with power of two dimensions or not.
The data is all the same, just the size of each vector and row relative to the full texture size changes.

Normally I would use a texture buffer, however this is WebGL code, and WebGL only supports textures.

Is there any way to make this kind of fetching matrices out of a texture reliable and consistent?

Comment: Did you set textures filtering to GL_NEAREST?

Comment: I did. I can even upload the test, if it interests anyone, assuming one can upload files on SO

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seems like this only happens on Hacintosh, so I guess there's a driver bug there handling NPOT textures. I am not quite sure how Hacintosh works, never installed Mac or had a Mac. I will check who I can report this bug to.

Answer (score 1):

If it interests anyone, the actual issue was indeed floating point errors. Since I sampled right on the boundary between pixels, even a tiny floating point error could cause the wrong pixel to be sampled. The solution is to sample in the middle of the pixel.

```
uniform sampler2D u_boneMap;
uniform float u_vector_size;
uniform float u_row_size;

mat4 boneAtIndex(float column, float row) {
    column *= u_vector_size * 4.0;
    row *= u_row_size;
    column += 0.5 * u_vectorSize;
    row += 0.5 * u_rowSize;

    return mat4(texture2D(u_boneMap, vec2(column, row)),
                texture2D(u_boneMap, vec2(column + u_vector_size, row)),
                texture2D(u_boneMap, vec2(column + u_vector_size * 2.0, row)),
                texture2D(u_boneMap, vec2(column + u_vector_size * 3.0, row)));
}
```

Comment: The issue is not numerical error since sampling from the very border of a texel does not guarantee any specific result, so even in a world without numerical error you would have still been at the odds of the specific graphics driver implementation.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks. It's very weird to think about, because I look at my textures as arrays of data with clear integer indices, kind of forgot textures and sampling is a bit more complex :)